# Sacrificing in response to a triggered ability that would place -1/-1 counters

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With the new Amonkhet series, if an ETB trigger says to put -1/-1 counters on target creature you control (e.g. [Baleful Ammit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBaleful%20Ammit%5d), [Exemplar of Strength](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExemplar%20of%20Strength%5d)), can you in response sacrifice that creature (supposing you have a sacrifice outlet) and not put the -1/-1 counters from the triggered ability on anything? I can't seem to find any info on this anywhere in the rules.

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed as unclear. It doesn't matter what "EOB" means. Having the exact ability text would be nice, but the OP provided enough details for the question to be answerable.

Comment: Editors, don't you think it changes the question to change "to have the counters fizzle" to "to not put the -1/-1 counters from the triggered ability"?

Comment: @Ikegami Agreed. Changing a question to use proper terminology doesn't help someone who is confused about that terminology.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can sacrifice the creature in response to targeting it with the enter the battlefield triggered ability and that will result in the ability being countered (fizzle) because it has no legal targets when it resolves and no -1/-1 counters will get placed on anything.

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. [...] The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal.

You should know that you must indicate that you wish to maintain priority as you identify the creature that you are targeting with the ability (e.g. "I will target my [Oashra Cultivator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOashra%20Cultivator%5d) with this ability and maintain priority. In response to the ability on the stack I will sacrifice my [Oashra Cultivator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOashra%20Cultivator%5d)"). This is more important when playing online or in formal play settings but it's a good habit to be in.

Comment: Re "*You should know that you must indicate that you wish to maintain priority*", ...when using tournament shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about an ability such as [Exemplar of Strength](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExemplar%20of%20Strength%5d)'s ability. Because it targets, the creatures to affect are chosen when the ability is placed on the stack, and it will indeed fizzle if none of its targets exist when it resolves.

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. [...] The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal.

Note that it's neither EoS or the counters that target and fizzle, but the ability on the stack.

Comment: ... Though that has nothing to do with the -1/-1 counters, but with the way 'targeting' works. Saccing a creature once it has the -1/-1 counters (assuming that didn't kill it in the first place) will also take away the counters.

Comment: Bad example of "fizzling" - Exemplar of Strength is a creature, so it will resolve regardless of what happens to the creature it targets with the -1/-1 counters. If the creature is removed before the spell resolves, no -1/-1 counters will be placed, but the spell as a whole doesn't fizzle.

Comment: @NuclearWang, it is the triggered ability that fizzles, not the creature spell. Ikegami, you might want to clarify that.

Comment: @steenbergh, Re "*Though that has nothing to do with the -1/-1 counters, but with the way 'targeting' works.*", Indeed. I didn't mention counters at all.

Comment: I know, and I personally didn't have trouble parsing it. But I can see how NuclearWang's misunderstanding could have happened, as it doesn't clearly talk about the distinction between the creature fizzling and the ETB trigger fizzling.

Comment: From the perspective of someone who doesn't know the rules as well as you or I, it would be easy to think of "an ability such as Exemplar of Strength's" as meaning the creature spell itself. (If you didn't know that spells and abilities are different, etc). But I think your recent edit is good and helpful.

Comment: Part of it could have simply been that it's easy to overlook an apostrophe and s in a word; especially due to the formatting of the card name being a hyperlink. "The ETB triggered ability on Exemplar of Strength" may help.

Comment: @GendoIkari, That changes the meaning to talk about EoS's ability specifically, and the OP didn't even mention EoS. I could add a redundant "ablity' after the "EoS's". This should finalize this.

Comment: @ikegami I know, but the question implied 'fizzling' had to do something with the effect rather than the mechanism.

Comment: @steenbergh, I still agree.

Answer (score 0):

The effect try to put -1/-1 effects on a target you chose when the effect is put on the stack. If the target is not present when the effect try to resolves, it fizzles and no counters is put on any creature. It's like any other effect that have a single target.